# Windows 7 hangs at Welcome screen with "EXPLORERFRAME.dll" error

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have a problem with my Windows 7 which fails to startup, and it happens frequently. I already tried to fix it, but nothing happened. I checked my hardisk and there is no badsector detected.

Its stop in the Welcome screen and I get the following message:

> C:\Windows\System32\EXPLORERFRAME.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or contains an error.

The Welcome screen then disappears and I get a totally empty screen with a cursor.

What happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you mean by "start up failure"? What exactly happens and where does it stop?

Comment: it stop in welcome screen and I get the following message:'C:\Windows\System32\EXPLORERFRAME.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or contains an eror
The welcome screen then disappears and i get a totally empty screen with a cursor

Comment: Thanks for adding details to your question. Please remember that for the future.

Comment: Try copying the file into the directory from a working Windows 7 install. You could also try booting to safe mode with command prompt or recovery console and running "sfc /scannow" which will verify the integrity of windows files. You can also just keep letting it fail until the windows boot diagnostic tool kicks in (I forget the name but it starts showing up after you fail booting a few times)

Comment: @Kyle offline SFC is not that easy, see this....http://mikemstech.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-perform-offline-system-integrity.html

Comment: It might be easier at this point to remove the harddrive and connect it to another computer as a slave/secondary drive, and copy all of your stuff off of it? Then re-partition your old drive and re-install windows, and finally, copy your files back. Just a thought anyway

Comment: Some good advice for gathering more info in the previous comments... Also, once you get the blank screen can you launch Task Manager by using CTRL-ALT-DEL? If yes, I would suggest using that to launch tools like Event Viewer and Process Monitor and also trying to launch explorer.exe manually - reply back if you want more details on how to do this (assuming you can get to Task Manager at all).

Comment: Can you boot and log into [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode)? if so can can you verify that the explorerframe.dll file exists.

Answer (score 1):

please try to go into the command prompt from a Windows install disk of your current os version, and run the following command "sfc /scannow" (no Quotes), this will hopefully revert the damaged system file to the original state.

If you do not feel confident to do this yourself then you <strike>could try a repair install (assuming you have a disk) or you</strike> may need to contact a local IT professional.

<strike>[Repair Install tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html?filter)</strike>

Please ignore the striked-out text, as it requires that you be able to boot into Windows. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kyle suggested, ask a friend with a clean system to copy that dll to a pendrive.
Then, boot from a linux live cd, insert the pendrive and replace the file.

All should be done now. If any problem persists, try to repair using the windows DVD or any other media containing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repair the corrupt files by typing the command `chkdsk /r /f` on c drive in command prompt. For opening the command prompt you have to boot your system with a bootable CD.

If it is Window's XP use recovery console by pressing R.
If it is Windows 7 Use repair method.
Or you can use bootsuite CD.

Answer (score -1):

1. open the task manager (to use it press ALT+CTRL+DELETE then choose start task manager)
2. click new task
3. then just click browse
4. click the help icon.
5. then search for system restore.
6. press the System restore:frequently asked questions
7. you will see there a sentence saying click to open system restore open it.
8. Then Just press next until you run system restore then just wait for the system restore to finish
9. then you're done you can use your computer properly again

Answer (score -3):

This happened to my computer minutes ago...

Follow these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>
2. Then select **Task Manager" (the last one)
3. Select **File->New Task (Run)...** then <kbd>Browse</kbd>
4. Locate `exlorerframe.dll`
5. Open your browser (start new process Opera=`opera.exe`, Firefox=`firefox.exe`, Google Chrome=`chrome.exe`, Internet Explorer `IEXPLORE.EXE`)
6. Download a matching `explorerframe.dll` (if you have 32bit system download x86 if you have 64 bit x64) (IF YOU TRIED TO MODIFY THE PREV. ONE AND YOU DIDN'T DELETE THE LAST ONE YOU CAN SKIP THIS)
7. If you downloaded one save it to `%WINDIR%\System32` (before doing it rename current explorerframe.dll to anything). If you can't rename, go the file's Properties->Security and give all access to yourself
8. Save the new file as `ExplorerFrame.dll`
9. With Task Manager again, run a new instance of `explorer.exe`

And you are done

Hope this will help, worked for me on Win7 Home premium 32bits (fully modded)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend downloading system files from the Internet due to the risk of malware infection. Instead I would recommend extracting required files from official Windows installation media as these files are known to be safe.

Comment: never EVER download system dll's. this may compromise your system security.